# I want to store variables into arrays (VB.NET)

Tags: arrays, vb.net, csv, multidimensional-array

I want my program to store my input into a csv file like this:

I write a word e.g. word

I write a definition e.g. definition

Then I write 5 errors e.g. error 1, error 2, error 3, error 4, error 5.

SO it looks something like this:

word, definition, error 1, error 2, error 3, error 4, error 5

word 2, definition 3, error 1, error 2, error 3, error 4, error 5

```
 Dim decision As Char
    Dim fullline As String = " "

    Dim word(9), def(9), minorerror(49) As String

    Console.Clear()

    Console.WriteLine("Select the year you will be saving the test for: ")
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("3 - Year 3")
    Console.WriteLine("4 - Year 4")
    Console.WriteLine("5 - Year 5")
    Console.WriteLine("6 - Year 6")


    Console.WriteLine()


    Dim testyear As Integer = Console.ReadLine()

    Select Case testyear

        Case 1
        Case 2
        Case 3
        Case 4

    End Select

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter 10 of your selected words, defenitions and selected amount minor errors to be featured in the following test")

    FileOpen(5, "F:\Computing\Spelling Bee\testtests.csv", OpenMode.Append)

    Do

        counter = counter + 1
        Console.Write("Word: ")
        word(counter) = Console.ReadLine
        Console.Write("Defenition: ")
        def(counter) = Console.ReadLine

        Console.WriteLine("Type in a max of 5 minor errors")

        For i As Integer = 1 To 5

            Console.Write("Minor error 1: ")
            minorerror(i + i) = Console.ReadLine
            'Console.Write("Minor error 2: ")
            'minoerror2(counter) = Console.ReadLine
            'Console.Write("Minor error 3: ")
            'minoerror3(counter) = Console.ReadLine
            'Console.Write("Minor error 4: ")
            'minoerror4(counter) = Console.ReadLine
            'Console.Write("Minor error 5: ")
            'minoerror5(counter) = Console.ReadLine

        Next

    Loop Until counter = 9
    Console.Clear()

    Dim x As Integer

    For counter As Integer = 0 To 9
        fullline = word(counter) & "," & def(counter) & "," & minorerror(x + counter)
        PrintLine(5, fullline)
        ' Console.WriteLine("Word: " & (word(counter.ToString)) & " Defenition: " & (def(counter.ToString)) & " Minor error 1: " & (minorerror1(counter.ToString)))
    Next

    Console.WriteLine("Are you sure you want to save this test? (y/n) ")
    decision = Console.ReadLine
    If decision = "y" Or decision = "Y" Then
        FileClose(5)
        staffmenu()
    ElseIf decision = "n" Or decision = "N" Then
        addtest()
```

I've been stuck on this for a while, my word and definition is being stored fine its just the errors.

I'm fairly new to coding and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you even tried anything? Show us your code please

Comment: We are not a custom software development service. Show us what you tried and where you find problems. PS: posts with the word "urgent" in their title rarely get a quick answer in SO (-> statistical fact).

Comment: I'm not that type of guy, I want to learn, not just simply get it and not understand it.

Comment: OK. Then better remove any reference to urgency and explain clearly what you want to accomplish exactly and why your code does not do what you want.

Comment: So I type in a word, the definition of that word and five acceptable minor errors of that word. I'm just having trouble storing the minor errors to my csv file.

Comment: I can do it, but the code is very cowboy'ish.

Comment: Your code is a bit chaotic and rely on too old approaches (you should use something like StreamWriter to write to the file). I think that the best advice I can give you is the one in my first comment: calm (= remove the urgency bit). Build the algorithm bit by bit and debug each part to make sure that it works before going ahead. I bet that you are not even sure if the problem is in the population of the arrays or in the writing part. Just set a break point, introduce some inputs and do a step-by-step execution to see how the program deals with these inputs at each point.

Comment: Never used stream writer before, I guess it's time to learn that then, thanks for the advice.

Comment: No problem. Just a small piece of advice more: if you want to extract information from various collections being iterated at the same time (now position 0, then position 1, etc.), you have to make sure that the population of these collections was done in parallel (same info for all the arrays in the first index, in the second)... Also you can add as many iterating variables as you wish (e.g., i, i2, i3) but better don't affect them from different places (e.g., for i = 0 to 100 myarray[i] = ""; NOT: myarray[i+10*k] = "" -> affecting i in two different places).

Comment: Really having trouble finding some core streamwriting tutorials/help...